# Is it possible to use AFNetworking in a TodayExtension?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, nsurlsession, today-extension

I'm using `AFNetworking` inside my iOS App without any problem. But now, I need to perform some API calls to my backend from my TodayExtension.

When I have tried to add any kind of `AFNetworking` class to my TodayExtension target, the compiler crash.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_AFNetworkingErrorDomain", referenced from:
      -[AFHTTPRequestOperation error] in AFHTTPRequestOperation.o
  "_AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey", referenced from:
      -[AFHTTPRequestOperation error] in AFHTTPRequestOperation.o
  "_AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey", referenced from:
      -[AFHTTPRequestOperation error] in AFHTTPRequestOperation.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_AFURLConnectionOperation", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperation in AFHTTPRequestOperation.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFURLConnectionOperation", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperation in AFHTTPRequestOperation.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is there any way to use it? What is the best way to call my API from TodayExtension? Maybe using `NSURLSession`?

Comment: Are you using CocoaPods?

Comment: Yes, but not for including AFNetworking

Comment: Okay, well since it's a linker error it seems like the static library or framework is missing from the `Link Binary With Libraries` section of `Build Phases`